# Yii 2 ActiveForm form field how to implement separator in checkboxlist?

Tags: php, forms, yii2, checkboxlist

```php
<?php
$form = ActiveForm::begin([
    'id' => 'form-id',
    'type' => ActiveForm::TYPE_HORIZONTAL,
    'options' => ['class' => 'well'],   
]);
?>

<?php
echo $form->field($model, 'MENU_DESC', ['template' => "{label}\n{input}\n{hint}\n{error}"])->checkboxList($menulist)->label(false);
?>

<?= Html::submitButton('submit', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary']) ?>
<?php ActiveForm::end();?>
```

May I know how to implement separator inside checkboxlist in yii2 form field?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is special option to achieve that. It's called `separator` and can be found in [official documentation](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-bootstrap-activefield.html#checkboxList%28%29-detail). You can pass any html that you want to use as a separator like this:

```
echo $form->field($model, 'MENU_DESC', ['template' => "{label}\n{input}\n{hint}\n{error}"])
    ->label(false)
    ->checkboxList($menulist, ['separator' => '<hr>']);
```

Also I don't recommend to name attributes like that (`MENU_DESC`), it looks like constant. And in case of reduced form of `description` or something like that, it's not good too. At first I thought it's order direction.

Comment: thanks! do u have any idea how to implement a "select all" option inside the checkboxlist as well?

Comment: Yes, I already did this before. But current problem is solved and this is kind of off-topic, you should create separate question for that.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28059193/yii-2-activeform-form-field-how-to-implement-select-all-option-in-checkboxlist hope u can help me thanks!

Comment: and sorry i took so long to update this, i wasn't getting any notifications from stackoverflow for replies.