# Yii 2 ActiveForm form field how to implement "select all" option in checkboxlist?

Tags: yii2, checkboxlist

Yii 2 ActiveForm form field how to implement "select all" option in checkboxlist?

```
<?php
$form = ActiveForm::begin([
    'id' => 'form-id',
    'type' => ActiveForm::TYPE_HORIZONTAL,
    'options' => ['class' => 'well'],   
]);
?>

<?php
    echo $form->field($model, 'MY_DESC', ['template' => "{label}\n{input}\n{hint}\n{error}"])
    ->label(false)
    ->checkboxList($mylist, ['separator' => '<hr>']);
?>

<?= Html::submitButton('submit', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary']) ?>
<?php ActiveForm::end();
?>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**1)** Add [checkbox](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-helpers-basehtml.html#checkbox%28%29-detail) to your form like so:

```
echo Html::checkbox(null, false, [
    'label' => 'Check all',
    'class' => 'check-all',
]);
```

**2)** Add some javascript to get it to work:

```
$('.check-all').click(function() {
    var selector = $(this).is(':checked') ? ':not(:checked)' : ':checked';

    $('#root-container-id input[type="checkbox"]' + selector).each(function() {
        $(this).trigger('click');
    });
});
```

Replace `#root-container-id` with the actual id of your container for that field. It should be something like Model name + dash + MENU_DESC. See it in generated html output. Or you can add another class or build selector with name of checkbox, it's up to you.

Then register this js, preferably with [assets](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-structure-assets.html).

Triggering click is used for correct work of client validation if it's enabled.

Comment: Thanks! u are a savior!